# How to prevent this white material in the receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, humidity, rain, insect

The receptacle is in hall and it rained straight for 3 days. I noticed this after 6 days since the rain started. It has developed some white thingy.

What's this? the other day I noticed a lizard sticking its head through this.

Is this white things because of lizard or something else

[image]

Comment: Was the lizard outside looking into the outlet? Or was it inside the outlet looking out? There's no a doubt that a lizard inside the outlet would be a problem. A lizard outside may electrocute itself. Inside it might electrocute then light on fire. It is hard to identify the stuff in the holes. You may have to turn the circuit off, test that it is off, then carefully oull the stuff out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to investigate further. It'll be hard to give confident answers from one blurry photo.

Some possibilities:

- Fungus
- Insect nesting
- Debris from insect or animal gnawing

The best advice I can offer is to seal gaps and dry things out.